# Getting all the <td> in same row

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I am creating a table dynamically through JSON data, but getting all `<td>` elements in same `<tr>` instead of two different rows.

JavaScript part :

```
$('button').click(function() {
var str = '[{"callType":"IN","extension":"150","name":"avis","phoneNumber":"9876541230","skill":"English","status":"INCALL","time":"10:50:23"},{"callType":"OUT","extension":"857","name":"sys","phoneNumber":"9658741235","skill":"Hindi","status":"WAITING","time":"08:40:51"}]';

var list = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    var tr = $('#t').append('<tr class="laOriginal" value="user"></tr>');
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="radioAgent" value="' + list[i].name + '" />"  id="radioAgent' + list[i].name + '"');
    tr.append(radioBtn);
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].extension + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].skill + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].phoneNumber + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].status + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].callType + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + list[i].time + "</td>");
}
});
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/s3rbG/2/)

How can I get data in two different rows?

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate `"<td>" + list[i].name + "</td>"` : what will happen if there's `</td>` in the name ? You should use the `text` function instead.

Comment: @dystroy If there's HTML in the name then the result of that HTML shows up in the `<td>`; that's not really an issue if they can at least guarantee that it's *correct* HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
var tr = $('#t').append('<tr class="laOriginal" value="user"></tr>');
```

Actually returns the jQuery object relating to `$('#t')`, not the generated `<tr>` element. You should swap the syntax around and use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

```
var tr = $('<tr class="laOriginal" value="user"></tr>').appendTo('#t');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3rbG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `var tr` is the value of $('#t'), not of your appended code.

What you want to do is: http://jsfiddle.net/s3rbG/5/

That is, save the newly-created tr in your var and then append it to the table. That way, when you append td elements to it, they're added to the tr, not the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {
var str = '[{"callType":"IN","extension":"150","name":"avis","phoneNumber":"9876541230","skill":"English","status":"INCALL","time":"10:50:23"},{"callType":"OUT","extension":"857","name":"sys","phoneNumber":"9658741235","skill":"Hindi","status":"WAITING","time":"08:40:51"}]';

var list = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    var new_tr = $('#t').append('<tr class="laOriginal" value="user"></tr>');
    var last_tr = $('#t tr :last' );
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="radioAgent" value="' + list[i].name + '" />"  id="radioAgent' + list[i].name + '"');
    last_tr.append(radioBtn);
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].name + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].extension + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].skill + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].phoneNumber + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].status + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].callType + "</td>");
    last_tr.append("<td>" + list[i].time + "</td>");
}
});
```